# Redux Can't Get State from Store

Tags: reactjs, redux

Edit: I am actually stuck here, can't solve it on my own and  a simple fix to code would help a lot.

I am currently working on a project and need to use redux-store , i try to pass value prop from app.js to AppRouter.js but when i try to access 'value' prop by logging it to console or rendering it ; i am getting undefined error both on console log and inside render value : . How can i overcome this? Any helps appreciated.

Here is my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {AppRouter} from './routers/AppRouter.js';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';


const initialState = {
    login: true,
    value: "10"
  };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if(action.type === "loginTrue") {
      return {
        login: true,
        value: "10"
      };
    }

    else{
        return {
        login: true,
        value: "10"
      };

    }
    return state;
};



const store = createStore(reducer,initialState);

store.dispatch({type: "loginTrue"});


const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter/>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(jsx,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is my AppRouter

```
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';
import {DashBoard} from '../components/DashBoard.js';
import {Login} from '../components/Login.js';
import {SignUp} from '../components/SignUp.js';
import {NotFoundPage} from '../components/NotFoundPage.js';
import {Header} from '../components/Header.js';
import {LoginSuccess} from '../components/LoginSuccess';
import {Failed} from '../components/Failed';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export const history = createHistory();

export class AppRouter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log("val "+ this.props.value);  //output val undefined
      return(

    <Router history={history}>
    <div>
        <Header />
        value: {this.props.value}                //outputs value : 
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={DashBoard} exact={true}/>
        <Route path="/login" component = {Login} />
        <Route path="/signup" component = {SignUp}/>
        <Route path="/loginSuccess" component = {LoginSuccess}/>
        <Route path="/failed" component = {Failed}/>
        <Route component = {NotFoundPage} />

    </Switch>
     </div>
    </Router>
    )
  }

};

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
        value: state.value
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AppRouter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem why you cannot get the redux state properly it's because your connected AppRouter it's default export, but in your App.js, you are using named import:

`import {AppRouter} from './routers/AppRouter.js';`

which it's the un-connected component, fix your import by:

`import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter.js';`

be careful with the export and import, this link might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export cheers

Comment: YOU MADE MY DAY BETTER SIR! I can't belive how compiler doesn't give any warnings or errors on that. It works now. Thank you a lot

Comment: @OğuzhanGöller it doesn't give a warning because it's not an error, the compiler just treated your code like you haven't use redux at all. happy coding~

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing value to AppRouter and that's why you don't get value in AppRouter component. What you need to do is pass value as a prp to AppRouter with value soething like below

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {AppRouter} from './routers/AppRouter.js';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';


const initialState = {
    login: true,
    value: "10"
  };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if(action.type === "loginTrue") {
      return {
        login: true,
        value: "10"
      };
    }

    else{
        login: true
    }
    return state;
};



const store = createStore(reducer,initialState);
console.log(store.getState());

const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter value={initialState.value}/>
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(jsx,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Now in AppRouter.js you will get this.props.value

Comment: I am a little bit confused since am trying to get data from redux-store rather than as argument, is your answer related to redux-store? Thanks for your answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

In the AppRouter.js since you don't have `mapDispatchToProps` variable, try to give the second argument of the "connect" method `null`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return {
        value: state.value
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AppRouter);
```

Comment: Thank for the answer but i am still getting same result.

Comment: Are you sure in the `const reducer`, if else statement passes to true, can you console.log() to check it out?

Comment: `if(action.type === "loginTrue")` do you have an external action component? 
I didnt get where the action.type is coming from

Comment: I already initialized the component , but i tried what you meant too; first i added "value: 10" to else statement, after that i called store.dispatch("loginTrue"); nothing changed

Comment: if you upload your project here: [link](https://codesandbox.io/) we can take a deeper look